# Protractor will not run with selenium grid

Tags: selenium, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to use the protractor to run the tests on the selenium grid, which runs on :

```
http://<ip_address>:4444/
```

In my config file I have:

```
seleniumAddress: "http://32.14.98.73:4444/wd/hub",
```

When I run the test, they are run locally and start the browser on the local system. ? Anything else is needed for this to work ?

In logs I have:

```
[18:20:05] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[18:20:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your config file for object directConnect to `directConnect:false`. For detailed understanding on `directConnect` and `seleniumAddress` refer the below link [Difference running Protractor with/without Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600738/difference-running-protractor-with-without-selenium)

Comment: that was exactly that